# Prove that $R = K\langle x,y,z\rangle/\langle x^2 - yz\rangle$ is an integral domain

Tags: algebraic-geometry, integral-domain, maximal-and-prime-ideals, singularity-theory, formal-power-series

Let $R = K\langle x,y,z\rangle/\langle x^2 - yz\rangle$ be an analytic algebra. I am trying to prove that $R$ is an integral domain.

Basically I know that if $\langle x^2 - yz\rangle$ is a prime ideal in $K\langle x,y,z\rangle$ it follows, that $R$ is an integral domain. But I'm having problems proving that.

Comment: **HINT:** $R \approx K[t^2,st,s^2]$.

Comment: What do you mean by $K\langle x \rangle$? Formal power series? Convergent power series?

Comment: @MooS: I would rather say that it is the algebra freely generated by $\{x,y,z\}$. In any case, it seems that the OP didn't mean polynomials. After the quotient, $R$ is the algebra freely generated by $\{x,y,z\}$, subjected to the constraint $x^2 = yz$.

Comment: @MooS: Yes $K\langle x,y,z \rangle$- it is the convergent power series ring over (a complete real valued) field.
And: analytic algebra  is isomorphic ( as an k-algebra) to the convergent power seires ring modulo an ideal of it.

Comment: @Fredrik Meyer : 
$\varphi: K \langle x,y,z \rangle \mapsto K\langle s,t \rangle$ a ringhomomrphism given by $\varphi(x) = s^2 , \varphi(y)=st, \varphi(z)=t^2$
and then I show that $ker \varphi = (x^2-yz)$ is the preimage of the ideal generated by 0 (there is only the element 0 in it ) in $K\langle s,t \rangle$
(because the preimage of a prime ideal under a ring map is a prime ideal)

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: correction :
 $\varphi(y) = s^2 , \varphi(x)=st, \varphi(z)=t^2$

Comment: @Ximango: If $\ker f$ were a prime ideal for any ring homomorphism $f$ defined on some ring $A$, then every ideal would be prime (!), because every ideal $I$ is the kernel of the canonical projection $A \mapsto A/I$. Therefore, your reasoning is flawed.

Comment: @Alex M. : But I don`t think that $ker\varphi$ is a prime ideal for every ringmorphism. 
But it is for those, where $\varphi(ker\varphi)$ is a prime ideal in A/I. Ker is the preimage of the zero ideal - and if the zero ideal is prime (in A/I), so is its preimage, or not?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean that $K$ is a field and so on, then yes, showing that it is irreducible should suffice.

You could also try writing out a multiplication of two non-zero elements and see when the product is zero.

Also, technically you don't know if the zero ideal is prime, since that is the same as being an integral domain.

Comment: At first, thanks for your reply! I'm afraid, I mixed a few things up in my original question, so there wasn't really a way to help me. But the question is now edited to represent my problem better.

Comment: I would see this as a comment, rather than an answer, merely because it doen't really answer the question.

Comment: @AlexM. well it was an answer to what the question was when I answered it. Might change it if I have the time to do that.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2-yz$ is irreducible by Eisenstein. In a factorial ring, any irreducible element generates a prime ideal.

Note that you should be careful about notions of irreducible. Irreducible ideals and irreducible elements are not the same notion. For example the ideal $(x^2)$ irreducible, but $x^2$ is of course not irreducible as an element of the polynomial ring.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I mixed a few things up in the original wording of the question. I edited an updated version that is hopefully less wrong :)

Comment: What version of Eisenstein is this? I only know [the one for polynomials in one indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), and this one needs the emphasizing of some prime ideal, which I do not recognize in your first brief sentence.

Comment: Isn't it pretty common that you use Eisenstein for multivariate polynomials? Nevertheless, the OP shoild clarify what precisely $R$ is...

Comment: Wow I am really disappointed by that Wikipedia article. It does not mention the usefulness of Eisenstein for showing irreducibility of multivariate polynomials with a single word. This is a stub.

Comment: @MooS: Exactly. The version that I myself know is for univariate polynomials, too. It would be very useful if you pointed me to a statement for multivariate polynomials, thank you.